# Python f.write() is not taking more arguments

Tags: python, file

I am having a python code like this

```
f=open('nv.csv','a+')
a=10+3
b=3+12
c=3+13
f.write(a,b,c)
```

This returns the output as

```
  f.write(a,b,c)
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem. I wish to enter every data into my file.

Comment: what is the desired output?  You probably want `f.write('{}\n'.format(a))` for each of your numbers? Or since it says 'csv', maybe you want `f.write({},{},{}\n'.format(a, b, c))`? That can be written like this, btw: `f.write(','.join(str(x) for x in (a, b, c)) + '\n')`. That's a bit more advanced.

Comment: I need values of a,b,c in my file. I will add many assignments in future

Comment: If you're writing csv files, use the csv module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`file.write` takes a single parameter, a string. You have to join your values and then write to the file. Lastly, do not forget to close your file:

```
f=open('nv.csv','a+')
a=10+3
b=3+12
c=3+13
f.write("{} {} {}\n".format(a, b, c))
f.close()
```

If you are going to multiple values later on, you should use a list:

```
s = [13, 15, 16, 45, 10, 20]
f.write(' '.join(map(str, s)))
f.close()
```

Edit:

Regarding you recent comments, you have two options.

Creating an initial dictionary:

```
s = {"a":13, "b":15, "c" = 16}
for a, b in s.items():
   f.write("{} {}\n".format(a, b))

f.close()
```

Or, using `globals` with a list:

```
s = [13, 15, 16, 45, 10, 20]
final_data = {a:b for a, b in globals().items() if b in s}
for a, b in final_data.items():
   f.write("{} {}\n".format(a, b))

f.close()
```

Comment: It return the output as a,b,c instead of values. How to get values of a,b,c in the file

Comment: @natarajanphysicist could you elaborate on what you mean by "output" and "values"?

Comment: I wish to get output file with values of variables such as a,b,and c(13,15,16). But it writes in the file with name of the variables itself.

Comment: @natarajanphysicist if this answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `f.writelines()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#module-io

```
f.writelines([a,b,c])
```

No line-separator is added.

If you want to have a special separator, use `"separator".join([str(i) for i in [a,b,c]])` and write this to file via `f.write()`

Answer (score 2):

all the previous are valid ones, and I will try to complete them

```
with open('nv.csv','a+') as f:
    a = 10 + 3
    b = 3 + 12
    c = 3 + 13
    f.write('{}\n'.format( ','.join(map(str, (a, b, c))) )
```

Comment: Hello, .join() is only working for strings. So this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

`f.write()` only takes one argument and write that into your file. If you want to write multiple components, you can use `f.writelines([a,b,c])`. Also, you can only write string to a file, so make sure to do `str(*)` for all your variables.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers suggested are good. If you want to make it more readable and neat, you can do this as well:

```
f.write("{a},{b},{c}".format(a=a, b=b, c=c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the % operator

Notice that the substitution variables x, y, z are all in parentheses, which means they are a single tuple passed to the % operator.

```
a=10+3
b=3+12
c=3+13
f.write("%s %s %s" % (a, b, c))
f.close()
```

Here is an [**example**](https://repl.it/Ner9) that you can execute online.

The code works perfectly.

The output is : *`13 15 16`*

Comment: It return the output as a,b,c instead of values.

Comment: it returns the output of the a, b, c values, the code has been tested. can you please copy the code you tested ?

Comment: f=open('ns.csv','w+')
a=10+3
b=3+12
c=3+13
f.write("%s %s %s" % (a, b, c))
f.close()