# Is there any other way to write into a file using more than one arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Is there any other way to write into a file using more than one arguments?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6iba.jpg)

`type error: write() takes exactly one argument (3 given)`

Comment: SO prefers all code to be in question rather than links.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python f.write() is not taking more arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078585/python-f-write-is-not-taking-more-arguments)

Comment: I am sorry for links but actually i tried to add the code but every time i tried to enter the code the question is not posting as there is code formatting error so i attached the link

Comment: @Noobprammer--I don't understand your problem, but if you post the code as regular text I could format it for you.  Also, my earlier comment provides a link to a similar question.

Comment: Thank you fellow member solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

f.write("=" * 40 + str("System Information") + str("=" * 40)) even this is working for my requirement

Answer (score -1):

Use the `file` parameter of `print` and give it a valid file handle. This way you can use an arbitraty amount of arguments.

`print(..., ..., ..., file=f)`

Note that you can adjust the `sep` parameter of the print function as required if you don't want to have your strings whitespace-separated.

Comment: f.write("=" * 40 + str("System Information") + str("=" * 40))  even this is working for my requirement